# Is there anyway to hide/show all blocks of comments?

Tags: c++, emacs, comments

[I've added c++ as a tag, but I'm not sure if I should... feel free to remove the tag if you don't deem it relevant.]

I have to work with .hpp/*.cpp with so much comments, no one bothers to read them.

To increase readability, I would like a way in emacs to just toggle hiding all blocks of comments, but not hide the code.

Perusing through the manual, there is a way to toggle hiding blocks of comments when hiding blocks of code.  But there doesn't appear to be a way to do what I wish.

Or is there?

thanks.

Comment: Do as Francis Glassborow suggested, configure your syntax coloring for comments as white on white.

Comment: Ah clever workaround, so +1 for you.   but it won't help much.  The problem is, there is so much comments, I may have 1 line of code per page.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library [`hide-comnt.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/hide-comnt.el) lets you [**hide or ignore comments**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideOrIgnoreComments).

You can do that interactively, using command **`hide/show-comments-toggle`**.  And you can do it from Lisp code temporarily, using macro **`with-comments-hidden`**.  Whether the macro has this effect is controlled by users, using option `ignore-comments-flag`.

Comment: You almost make me try Emacs again. I think last time was 1994 or thereabouts.

Comment: Thanks.  I want to try this out before I give you the check, is that okay?  But quick question, do I think of this el as an add add-on to hide-show minor mode?  Does it replace it?

Comment: It is unrelated to hide-show minor mode. Try it to see if it helps in your context. I use it for Emacs-Lisp buffers, but I've tried it only a bit on C buffers, and not at all on C++. You are welcome to mail me a suggestion or bug report (see the file header for contact info).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - ***;-)***

Comment: Okay, thanks again, I will have some free time this afternoon, I will try it then.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you this late, but man... this is awesome!!! Thanks.  When looking at one line of code per page at times, this has really helped.  Perhaps one suggestion I can make, is if there can be a hide/show toggle that's block-level aware.  For instance, I just want the quotes hidden in the loop that I am examining.  I see there's a way to do it by region, but it be nice if there was a fun() that the way I described, much like hs-mode has this ability.  But that's minor right now, this is a tremendous help.  I will email you more suggestions as I have them.  Thanks a million!!

Comment: The same command does what you ask for if the region is active. Just select some text and then try the command. Only the selected text will have its comments hidden/revealed.